# Raising asynchronous events in python

Tags: python, events, asynchronous

I wanted to make Class structure, where in the flow is controlled by generation of events. For that, I did the following:

```
class MyEvent:  
    EventName_FunctionName = {}

    @classmethod
    def setup(cls, notificationname, functionname):
        if notificationname in MyEvent.EventName_FunctionName.keys():
            MyEvent.EventName_FunctionName[notificationname].append(functionname)
        else:
            MyEvent.EventName_FunctionName[notificationname] = [functionname]

    @classmethod    
    def runonnotification(cls, notificationname, *args):
        thisfunclist = MyEvent.EventName_FunctionName[notificationname]
        for func in thisfunclist:
            if len(args) > 0:
                func(*args)
            else:
                func()
```

And then use it in the following way:

```
from FirstEventClass import MyEvent
class simpleexample:
    def __init__(self,a = 1, b = 2):
        simpleexample.a = a
        simpleexample.b = b
        MyEvent.setup('greater than 100',self.printerror)
        MyEvent.setup('dont do negative',self.negation)
        MyEvent.setup('many values recieved',self.handlemultipleupdates)


    def updation(self,updateval):
        if updateval > 100:
            MyEvent.runonnotification('greater than 100',updateval)
            self.a = updateval
        if updateval < 0:
            MyEvent.runonnotification('dont do negative')


    def multipleupdates(self, a, b):
        MyEvent.runonnotification('many values recieved', a , b)

    def printerror(self,data):
        print ' something has gone wrong' ,data

    def negation(self):
        print 'negation enter'
        self.a = -self.a

    def handlemultipleupdates(self, a , b):
        print 'wow'
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
```

However, my problem is that basically all these events are function calls and after a shortwhile, I build a huge stack of recursive calls. How can I either exit functions along with notifying events, or keep running existing function on background thread.

Comment: can you include some code which uses those classes?

Comment: Why have you used a class attribute and class methods, instead of either having a normal instance, or just making things global? This smells like you're trying to write Java in Python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could:

- Use [ThreadPools](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.pool). Same interface as process pools, but imported from `multiprocessing.pool` like so `from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool`.

  You could send event name and args to the pool for threads to handle. **This could block if the queue is full.**
- Create a simple event queue (django models) in the database and use separate processes/threads to handle events. This won't block as you can mostly always add new objects to the db.
- Check out libraries like [celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/) which give you scalabilty, and make it possible to build whole event dispatcher on top of the queue.

`ThreadPool` example:

```
from collections import defaultdict
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool


class MyEvent:
    handlers = defaultdict(list)
    _pool = ThreadPool(5)

    @classmethod
    def setup(cls, notificationname, functionname):
        cls.handlers[notificationname].append(functionname)

    @classmethod
    def runonnotification(cls, notificationname, *args):
        thisfunclist = cls.handlers[notificationname]
        for func in thisfunclist:
            cls._pool.apply_async(func, args=args)


class SimpleExample(object):
    def __init__(self, a=1, b=2):
        SimpleExample.a = a
        SimpleExample.b = b
        MyEvent.setup('greater than 100', self.printerror)
        MyEvent.setup('dont do negative', self.negation)
        MyEvent.setup('many values recieved', self.handlemultipleupdates)

    def updation(self, updateval):
        if updateval > 100:
            MyEvent.runonnotification('greater than 100', updateval)
            self.a = updateval
        if updateval < 0:
            MyEvent.runonnotification('dont do negative')

    def multipleupdates(self, a, b):
        MyEvent.runonnotification('many values recieved', a, b)

    def printerror(self, data):
        print 'something has gone wrong ', data

    def negation(self):
        print 'negation enter'
        self.a = -self.a

    def handlemultipleupdates(self, a, b):
        print 'wow'
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

s = SimpleExample()
for x in [-50, 0, 1, 50, 70, 101]:
    s.updation(x)

MyEvent._pool.close()
MyEvent._pool.join()
```

Comment: could you possibly give some simple example. by the way, i also tried a lightweight library called axel.events, which supposedly allows for new threads.

Comment: Would be very useful for searchers to have the widely-used `celery` example too.